# ng-disabled not working on Submit button in AngularJS 1.4.8

Tags: angularjs

This is my first AngularJS contact form (new to AngularJS). I've read many posts about this problem and tried many solutions, but I can't get it. Seems simple enough but I'm stumped.

I want to disable the Submit button until the required inputs (email and comments) have been populated.

Also, the email and comments error messages display immediately on page load instead of waiting for the blur.

This is the correct js (the script I was using was from a tutorial, which I misunderstood):

```
angular.module('contForm', [])
    .controller('contCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
})

<form ng-app="contForm" ng-controller="contCtrl" name="mailForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name"  size="31" maxlength="50"><br>

    <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="user.phone" size="31" maxlength="12"><br>

    <span ng-show="mailForm.email.$touched && mailForm.email.$invalid">Please enter your email address. </span> 

    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" size="31" maxlength="100" required><br>

    <span ng-show="mailForm.contComments.$touched && mailForm.contComments.$invalid">Please enter your comments. </span>                        

    <input type="text" name="contComments" ng-model="user.comments" required><br>

    <input type="submit" name="subComments" value="SEND" ng-disabled="mailForm.$invalid">
</form>
```

Comment: I put your code here (with some changes):  http://plnkr.co/edit/UUm2EiA4Sb6HaIi1IEJM?p=preview. I don't see the problems you mention.

Comment: I see what you mean. The problems aren't there. It must be something else in my test page that's interfering. I'll work on it.

Comment: Pretty weird, same code on jsfiddle doesn't seem to work. In fact, the <pre> doesn't return true, weird. https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/y79woxph/

Comment: @Syden, if you change the jsfiddle to put Angular in the `head` instead of loading it `onLoad`, it works.

Comment: @fuey, so there are no problems now, right?

Comment: @Ine yes you are correct, however I needed to add jquery as well, thought lite version came bundled on angular's min file. Thanks though! ;)

Comment: @Maria, no problems. You're mighty smart.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't find that error, i think your source is not complete, i used cdn angularjs.

```css
input.btn[disabled] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

    <form ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" name="mailForm" novalidate>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" size="31" maxlength="50"><br>

        <input type="text" name="phone" ng-model="user.phone" size="31" maxlength="12"><br>

        <span ng-show="mailForm.email.$touched && mailForm.email.$invalid">Please enter your email address. </span>

        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" size="31" maxlength="100" required><br>

        <span ng-show="mailForm.contComments.$touched && mailForm.contComments.$invalid">Please enter your comments. </span>

        <input type="text" name="contComments" ng-model="user.comments" required><br>

        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="subComments" value="SEND" ng-disabled="mailForm.$invalid">
    </form>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("app", []);

        app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```